# Python dataframe summarised by group, create list in column

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, aggregate

hope you guys can indicate with pandas functions i need to use in order to achieve the desired output.

Example input (real data will have v4, v5, v6, .... v20 on the right hand side)

```
Year        v1      Month   v2          v3
2001        1.5     1       11.50       11.00
2001        1.5     2       12.50       12.00
2001        1.5     3       13.50       13.00
2001        1.5     4       14.50       14.00
2001        1.5     5       15.50       15.00
2001        1.5     6       16.50       16.00
2002        2.5     1       12.77       12.27
2002        2.5     2       13.88       13.38
2002        2.5     3       14.99       14.49
2002        2.5     4       16.10       15.60
2002        2.5     5       17.21       16.71
2002        2.5     6       18.32       17.82
2003        3.5     1       14.17       13.67
2003        3.5     2       15.40       14.90
2003        3.5     3       16.63       16.13
2003        3.5     4       17.87       17.37
2003        3.5     5       19.10       18.60
2003        3.5     6       20.33       19.83
```

Desired Output:

```
Year    v1      Month
2001    1.5     [{[v2:11.5], [v3:11]}, {[v2:12.5],[v3:12]}, {..}, {..}, {..}, {..}}]
2002    2.5     [{[v2:12.77], [v3:12.27]}, {[v2:13.88],[v3:13.38]}, {..}, {..}, {..}, {..}}]
2003    3.5     [{[v2:14.17], [v3:13.67]}, {[v2:15.4],[v3:14.9]}, {..}, {..}, {..}, {..}}]
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `groupby` and `to_dict`:

```
df.groupby(['Year', 'v1'])[['v2', 'v3']].apply(
    pd.DataFrame.to_dict, orient='records',
)
```

Output:

```
Year  v1 
2001  1.5    [{'v2': 11.5, 'v3': 11.0}, {'v2': 12.5, 'v3': ...
2002  2.5    [{'v2': 12.77, 'v3': 12.27}, {'v2': 13.88, 'v3...
2003  3.5    [{'v2': 14.17, 'v3': 13.67}, {'v2': 15.4, 'v3'...
```

Comment: Cheers. Thats exactly what i needed!

Comment: Great! Can you please mark the answer as accepted then? Thanks!

Comment: one additional comment, how can i structure it to be a dataframe? year as first column instead of index, then v1 as second column, and call the third one as 'by month'

Comment: What you get with the above is a pandas Series, so if you add `.rename('by month').reset_index()`, you'll get a DataFrame with the 'Year', 'v1', 'by month' columns

Comment: thanks a lot perl, thats what i was confused with, the different object types and how to convert them to one or another, ie Groupby, series etc..... would be good if you can recommend any good source that explains in details :)